# How to send and receive data between RPi and PIC33E microcontroller via USB?.

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, hardware, data-transfer

This is my first project with **PIC33E**, and both the devices will be connected by USB only.

Rpi will have a User Interface (**written in Python**) and which will enable the user to send and receive data.

PIC33E(**planning to write the codes in objective C**) will be connected to a bunch of sensors and few other PIC18 microcontrollers. Also, receive commands from Rpi and send it to PIC18 and send signals from the sensors to RPI.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement the device USB stack on PIC33E. the easiest one (and will not require any additional drivers on the RPi side is the Virtula COM port (CDC device).

You will be able to communicate with your device same way as with any other serial device.